# Scala protected constructor and builder in companion object

Tags: scala, constructor, factory, protected

I have some classes with a protected constructor and the factory method is inside the companion object of an abstract super class. As of Scala 2.9.0.RC4 this doesn't compile anymore. I have "fixed" the issue by making the constructors *package protected*. But I don't want other classes even inside the same package to be able to call the constructors.

So what should I?

```
sealed abstract class A
object A {
  //the factory method, returning either a B or C
  def apply(): A
}
class B protected (...) extends A
class C protected (...) extends A
```

Comment: I'd raise a bug about this, particularly if it worked on 2.8.1 and as recently as RC3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make them private inner classes of the object.

```
object A {
  private class B extends A
  private class C extends A
}
```

Comment: Thought about that. But they get often used in pattern matching and then I'd have to - hmmm, maybe only import statements would change?

Comment: I think you should have made a second answer instead of changing this one. After all maybe the old one is helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the classes accessible for pattern matching, I would suggest creating a new subpackage for them and making the constructor private to that package. Now only the import statements in your client code need to be changed.

```
sealed abstract class A {

}
package myPackage.subPackage {

object A {
  def apply(): A = new B
}

class B private[subPackage] () extends A {

}
}

package other {
  object Foo {
    def foo {
      myPackage.subPackage.A()
      //does not compile: new myPackage.subPackage.B
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create companion objects for each implementation of A and delegate construction to a factory method in this object:

```
sealed abstract class A
object A {
  //the factory method, returning either a B or C
  def apply(): A = {
    if (...) B()
    else C()
  }
}
object B {
  def apply() : B = new B()
}
class B private (...) extends A

object C {
  def apply() : C = new C()
}
class C private (...) extends A
```